# NoModuleError: 'No module named pandas' while executing the .bat file

Tags: python, pandas, batch-file

I'm trying to a run .bat file, which has a link to python code in my PC.

This is the code in my `createExeFile_dummy.py` file

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'Name':['check','Pqr','Abc'],'Age':[12,34,22],'Address':['icgb','ctgcad','kjsbfdjk']})
df.to_csv('D:/Test/chkexe.csv',index=False)
```

the .bat file has `"C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe" "D:\Test\createExeFile_dummy.py"`
When I try to double click this bat file it gives me error **NoModuleError: 'No module named pandas'**
But when I try to run the python script in my spyder editor, it runs completely fine.
Any suggestion?

P.S : I have been following this [link](https://datatofish.com/python-script-windows-scheduler/) to create the .bat file

Comment: Is the path to your python.exe in your batch file pointing to the correct version of Python?

Comment: yes @dishantmakwana

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you installed Spyder, it may be referencing a different Python executable (not `C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe`) where you have `pandas` installed.

To check this, run

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

in both Spyder and in the .bat file and see if they match.

Comment: The above script when I run in spyder give "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\pythonw.exe"

Comment: That means you installed Spyder via [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/).  Anaconda is it's own self-container Python distribution, separate and apart from the Python installed on your PC in `C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs`.  The easiest way to fix your current issue is to change the path to the Python executable in your .bat file to the path of the Python executable used by Spyder

Comment: I tried with "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe", but still not working

Comment: @deepesh `C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe` is the path to the Python executable where pandas **isn't** installed.  Importing `pandas` is working in Spyder, so the Python version Spyder is using **does** have `pandas`.  In your .bat file, change `C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe` to `C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\pythonw.exe`